# Error: Firestore has already been initialized. You can only call settings() once, and only before calling any other methods on a Firestore object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js, emulation, firebase-security

So I'm writing tests for firebase rules so I can create reproducible code for another question I'm writing on stackoverflow and I get this error:

```
$ mocha test2.js 


  Our social app
    1) Can read a single public post


  0 passing (245ms)
  1 failing

  1) Our social app
       Can read a single public post:
     Error: Firestore has already been initialized. You can only call settings() once, and only before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.
      at Firestore.settings (node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:434:19)
      at getAdminFirestore (test2.js:41:9)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test2.js:60:23)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

It seems like it doesn't like that I use `admin.settings(dbSettings)` in the getAdminFirestore function but if I comment it out, then it throws

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Users\julien\Documents\GitHub\reloadium\test\test2.js)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Probably because then it doesn't find the emulator port?

`test2.js`

```js
/* eslint-env mocha */
const firebase = require('@firebase/rules-unit-testing');
const firestoreEmulatorPort = 8081;
const dbSettings = { 
  host: `localhost:${firestoreEmulatorPort}`, 
  ssl: false,
}
const MY_PROJECT_ID = "test";
const theirId = "user_xyz";

function getFirestore(
  auth,
) {
  var db = firebase.initializeTestApp(
    {
      projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
      auth: auth
    }
  )
  .firestore()

  db.settings(
    dbSettings
  )
  

  return (
    db
  )
}

function getAdminFirestore(
) {
  var admin = firebase.initializeAdminApp(
    {
      projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID
    }
  )
  .firestore()

  admin.settings(
    dbSettings
  )

  return (
    admin
  )
}

describe(
  "Our social app", 
  (

  ) => {
    it(
      "Can read a single public post", 
      async (

      ) => {
        const admin = getAdminFirestore();

        const postId = "public_post"
        const setupDoc = admin.collection(
          "posts"
        ).doc(
          postId
        )

        await setupDoc.set(
          {
            authorId: theirId,
            visibility: "public"
          }
        )

        const db = getFirestore(null)

        const testRead= db.collection(
          "posts"
        ).doc(
          postId
        )

        await firebase.assertSucceeds(
          testRead.get()
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

`firestore.rules`

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId}{
      allow read:if (
        (
          resource.data.visibility == "public"
        ) || 
        (
          resource.data.authorId == request.auth.uid
        )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem by setting the firestore emulator port environment variable
`FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081`
instead of setting the port in

```
const firestoreEmulatorPort = 8081;
const dbSettings = { 
  host: `localhost:${firestoreEmulatorPort}`, 
  ssl: false,
}

db.settings(dbSettings)
```

I removed this from my code